# Returning rows with same key when searching only one of them

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is returning results:

```
DECLARE @VALUE_LIST varchar(1000) = 'B1'
select * from mfr_attr 
where attr_val like '%' + @VALUE_LIST + '%' and field_id = 90
```

[image]

I want the 'like' statement to evaluate only on field_id = 90 but return all other rows too.

Above I think what is wrong is that by using where  field_id = 90 it doesn't return the other field_id's but I need it the like statement to only evaluate against field_id = 90.

Comment: So, what would be the result that you actually want to get?, `I want the 'like' statement to evaluate only on field_id = 90 but return all other rows too` what does this mean?

Comment: @Siyual got it, but I mean rows with any field_id.

Comment: actually no I don't think, this is returning all rows and isn't using the like filter.

Comment: You are using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @JohnConde Using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `exists()`:

```
DECLARE @VALUE_LIST varchar(1000) = 'B1'
select * from mfr_attr m
where exists (
  select 1 
  from mfr_attr i
  where i.attr_val like '%' + @VALUE_LIST + '%' 
    and i.field_id = 90
    and i.item_id = m.item_id
    )
```

This will return all rows for an `item_id` where that `item_id` has a row with `field_id = 90` and the `attr_val` for that row is like your like condition.

Comment: Wouldn't that return the same results as the query in the question, or am I missing something due to the late hour?

Comment: @ZoharPeled The table is most likely an **EAV** table, in which case OP wants all of the rows related to any `entity` that has a `value` like the`like` for `attribute = 90`. Where `entity = item_id`, `attribute=field_id` and `value=attr_val`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to group the two conditions and use an `OR` for the rest:

```
Declare @VALUE_LIST Varchar(1000) = 'B1';
Select  *
From    mfr_attr
Where   (field_id = 90 And attr_val Like '%' + @VALUE_LIST + '%')
Or      field_id != 90;
```

Comment: I thought this was it but this is returning all rows and isn't using the like filter.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Are you sure?  This should only apply the `like` filter to records where `field_id = 90`, but it will still return everything else.  Is that not what you were looking for?